# Resource Controller in a named Route group causing route name issue?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a resource controller in a named route group, as follows:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'ldapauth', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    // other routes ...

    Route::resource('institution', 'InstitutionController');

});
```

And I'm getting an extra "admin" for the route names belonging to the resource controller routes, see here:

```
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| URI                                 | Name                           |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| admin                               | admin.dashboard                |
| admin/email/{id}                    | admin.email.show               |
| admin/institution                   | admin.admin.institution.index  |
| admin/institution                   | admin.admin.institution.store  |
| admin/institution/contact           | admin.institution.contact      |
| admin/institution/create            | admin.admin.institution.create |
| admin/institution/{institution}     | admin.                         |
| admin/institution/{institution}     | admin.admin.institution.destroy|
| admin/institution/{institution}     | admin.admin.institution.update |
| admin/institution/{institution}     | admin.admin.institution.show   |
| admin/institution/{institution}/edit| admin.admin.institution.edit   |
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Do I need to remove the resource controller outside of the group then reapply middleware etc?

Edit: I would like to keep the named `'as' => 'admin.'` on the route group so I don't need to prefix all the routes in the group. So is this possible?

Comment: Try to remove `'as' => 'admin.'`

Comment: The question should probably be, *Can I have a route resource in a named route group?* I want to keep it there so I don't have to prefix all my other routes that are not route resources

Comment: Just try to remove prefix and see the difference.

Comment: Removing `prefix` means I have to append `admin` to all the normal routes' url, so it doesn't solve the issue. I'm pretty sure it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage this is, passing middlewares in controller, add a construct to your controller, that would be like this:

```
class InstitutionController extends Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('ldapauth');
    }

}
```

After that you can create resource:

```
Route::resource('admin/institution', 'Admin\InstitutionController');
```

Now you can access to route using:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('admin.institution.contact')]) !!}
```

Also, you can see all the current routes with `php artisan route:list`. And you see a similar ouput of routing.